# Comparing one table column against another column using SUMPRODUCT

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am looking into writing a formula that counts how many entries in a column *Data[Country]* match a list determined in a separate table column *Included[Countries]*.

I have tried using the `SUMPRODUCT` function as below:

=`SUMPRODUCT(--(Data[Country]=Included[Countries]))`

but this returns an error. If I replace *Included[Countries]* by an array of the constituents, e.g. `=SUMPRODUCT(--(Data[Country]={"EN","DE"}))`, this works, however I want to avoid harcoded values.

I have also tried `COUNTIFS(Data[Country], Included[Countries])` but this has not worked.

Any ideas please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`=SUMPRODUCT(--(Data[Country]=Included[Countries]))` does not work as SUMPRODUCT expects the two ranges to be the same size at it will iterate both row by row.  If they are different sizes it will return an error.

`=SUMPRODUCT(--(Data[Country]=Included[Countries]))` works because you are using an array and not a range.

`=COUNTIFS(Data[Country], Included[Countries])` does not iterate on its own and thus will only return the first cell count.

To get it to iterate use COUNTIFS() inside SUMPRODUCT():

```
=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIFS(Data[Country], Included[Countries]))
```

So, you were close to the solution, just needed to understand how to combine the two approaches.

Comment: Thanks Scott, that works! Though I do not quite understand why. Why doesn't either function alone work but combining the two together does? Using the 'Evaluate Formula' functionality I can see that the column is treated differently depending on which formula it is an argument for.

Comment: @Maria so doing it this way is akin to `COUNTIFS(Data[Country],"EN") + COUNTIFS(Data[Country],"DE")`  it is literally doing a new countif for each cell in `Included[Countries]`  The SUMPRODUCT forces the iteration and maintains the sum.  COUNTIFS by itself will not iterate, not designed to do that, so we need use something  else to do it.

Comment: @Maria also remember to mark as correct after the question is 15 minutes old by clicking the check mark by the answer.

Comment: Thanks @Scott, that's been most helpful. I've marked the answer as correct and upvoted it. :)